# pymongo+MongoDB: How to find _id in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to find the `_id` of a document of a collection `(mycol)` where `"name":"John"`.  I have inserted the document but want to find the `_id` of document. Is it possible ? I am trying as

```
result = db.mycol.find({"_id": {"name": "John"}})
```

But it is returning a cursor object.

> pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x00000000030E3DD8>

Then I tried as

```
for itm in result:
            print (itm)
```

But it is not printing anything.

Comment: Of course it is possible but did you actually try anyhting? This is so basic that it should be easy to find plenty of material when using some search engine

Comment: @DAXaholic Question Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like that

```
result = db.mycol.find({"name": "John"})
for item in result:
    print(item['_id'])
```

Just have a look at the [docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document) to see how to use pymongo

Comment: If we are finding `_id` from `result.item._id` then why `_id` in `db.mycol.find({"_id": {"name": "John"}})`

Comment: "why `_id in db.mycol.find({"_id": {"name": "John"}})`" --> That's your code - not mine. I don't know why you tried it like that

Comment: It is giving the error  `print(item.id_)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id_'`

Comment: I tried both  `print(item._id)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_id'` and `print(item.id_) AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id_'` both giving error.

Comment: Try `print(item['_id'])` - I was used to PowerShell in the meantime which allows accessing dict entries directly - sry

Comment: Got it.. It is working. Why it works with `print(item['_id']`? not above.

Comment: Well that's just how dictionaries work in python. Please accept the answer as it obviously works for you now - thx

Comment: @user3787092 you should cover some basic Python tutorials first.